# To what extent can values of $n$ such that $n^2-n+41$ is composite be predicted?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Euler's polynomial $E(n)=n^2-n+41$ takes a prime value for each of the positive integers $n<41$.  For $n=41$, its value is $41^2$, which is composite, and every multiple of 41 will likewise produce a composite number.  These, of course, aren't the only $n$ for which $E(n)$ is composite.  Between $41$ and $82=2\cdot41$, for example, we have $$
(42,45,50,57,66,77)=(41+1,41+4,41+9,41+16,41+25,41+36)
$$
which all give $E(n)$ composite; in the range $1\le n\le1000$ there are 419 values of $n$ for which $E(n)$ is composite.

You can show that $E(n)$ will be composite when $n=f_1(a,b):=a(b^2-b+41)+b$ for $a$ a positive integer and $b$ an arbitrary integer.  This is readily done by plugging $f_1(a,b)$ into $E(n)$, factorizing the resulting polynomial as $(b^2-b+41)(a^2b^2-a(a-2)b+1-a+41a^2)$, and verifying that neither factor equals 1 for the stated values of $a$ and $b$.

Remarkably, the first 61 values of $n$ that produce composite $E(n)$ are of this form, with $n=245$ being the smallest exception.

Another expression that always produces composite $E(n)$, and for similar reasons, is $n=f_2(a,b):=(4a+2)(b^2-b+41)+(4a+1)b-a$.  Together, $f_1(a,b)$ and $f_2(a,b)$ account for the first 169 values of $n$ for which $E(n)$ is composite, with $n=490$ being the first exception.  Two additional expressions, $f_3(a,b):=(a + 1) a (b^2-b+41) + (2 a + 1) b - (a - 1)$ and $f_4(a,b):=\frac{1}{2}(a + 1) a (b^2-b+41) + (2 a + 1) b - (a - 2)$, along with $f_1(a,b)$ and $f_2(a,b)$ account for all composite-producing $n$ less than 979.

**Questions:**

1. Can someone see what's going on here?  What is the conceptual explanation for the success of these particular expressions in accounting for low-lying composite-producing $n$?
2. Should we expect to find more such expressions?  All of the $f_j$ defined above are quadratic in $b$, but not necessarily in $a$.

**Motivation:**
I became curious about this question while investigating the work of [Laurence Monroe Klauber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurence_Monroe_Klauber).  He is most famous for his work in herpetology, but he also pursued an interest in number theory, which I became aware of through reading [one](http://www.maa.org/editorial/mathgames/mathgames_07_17_06.html) of Ed Pegg Jr.'s *Math Games* columns.  (Klauber developed the idea of using two-dimensional arrays of integers to visualize prime-rich quadratic polynomials decades before Ulam discovered his spiral.)  The San Diego Natural History Museum has recently been digitizing some of Klauber's papers; Margaret Dykens, the librarian there, sent me the abstract of a talk Klauber gave at an MAA meeting in 1932, in which he mentions patterns in the composite values of the Euler polynomial.  I have not yet seen the paper itself - it wasn't published - so I don't know what Klauber claimed to have found.  The expressions $f_i(a,b)$ above were found by fitting lists of composites generated by the computer.

Comment: Yes, I gather that that was Klauber's motivation.  In his notes, he highlights $n^2+n-109$ which produces many primes, although not as many as Euler's polynomial.

Answer (score 5):

For any $p$, $E(x+p) \equiv E(x)\mod p$.  Moreover, $E(x) - E(y) = (x-y)(x+y-1)$. 
If $p < 41$, $E(x)$ is not divisible by $p$ for $0 \le x \le 40$, so $E(x)$ is never divisible by $p$.   Thus $E(x)$ is never divisible by a prime $< 41$.   For moderately sized integers, that rules out a lot of the composites.

On the other hand, if $p = E(b)$, then $E(a p + b) \equiv E(b) \equiv 0 \mod p$.  That's your $f_1(a,b)$. Since $E(x) - E(y) = (x- y)(x + y - 1)$, if $p = E(b)$ is prime the only other $x < p$ for which $E(x) \equiv 0 \mod p$ is $p + 1 - b$, and then
also $E(a p + 1 - b) \equiv 0 \mod p$.  Note that $p + 1 - b = f_1(1,b-1)$,
$2p + 1 - b = f_3(1,b-1)$, and $3p + 1 - b = f_4(2, b-1)$. I don't see how to get $4 p + 1 - b$ from your polynomials though.  For example, how do you account for $E(594) = 151 \times 2333$, where $594 = 4 E(11) - 10$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which I will take time to think about more carefully later.  I just wanted to give a quick answer to your question about $E(594)$.  I allow $b$ to be negative, so you can obtain 594 as $f_1(4,-10)=4E(-10)-10$.  This works because $E(11)=E(-10)$.

Comment: Ah, of course, $a p + 1 - b = a E(1-b) + 1-b = f_1(a,b')$ where $b' = 1-b$.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to derive your $f_2(a,b)$ (and a new polynomial) as follows.  Suppose we look for $f(b) = c_2 b^2 + c_1 b + c_0$ such that $E(f(b))$ is divisible by $e_2 b^2 + e_0$ (as polynomials in $b$ with coefficients in the field generated by the parameters) .  The remainder on division of $E(f(b))$ by $e_2 b^2 + e_0$ is
$$ {\frac {c_{{1}} \left( 2\,e_{{2}}c_{{0}}-e_{{2}}-2\,e_{{0}}c_{{2}}
 \right) b}{e_{{2}}}}+{\frac {41\,{e_{{2}}}^{2}+{e_{{0}}}^{2}{c_{{2}}}
^{2}+{e_{{2}}}^{2}{c_{{0}}}^{2}-e_{{0}}e_{{2}}{c_{{1}}}^{2}-{e_{{2}}}^
{2}c_{{0}}-2\,e_{{0}}e_{{2}}c_{{2}}c_{{0}}+e_{{0}}e_{{2}}c_{{2}}}{{e_{
{2}}}^{2}}}$$

Solving for the coefficients of this to be 0, the solution Maple provides that doesn't involve
irrationals is $$c_0 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{163 c_2}{4 c_1^2}, \ e_0 = \frac{163 e_2}{4 c_1^2}$$

One possibility is for $c_2$ to be a multiple of $c_1^2$: considering the first equation mod 4, we get $c_1 = s$,  $c_2 = (4 t + 2) s^2$, $c_0 = 82 + 163 t$.    The result is $f(b)  =  (4t + 2) (s b)^2 + sb + 82 + 163 t$, where $E(f(b))$ is divisible by
$4 b^2 + 163$.
  With $t=a$ and $s=-1$ this is your $f_2(a,b)$.  Note that $s=-1$ is no loss of generality since $f(b)$ depends on $b$ only through $sb$.

The other possibility is for $c_2$ to be a multiple of $163 s^2$: we get $c_1 = 163 s$, $c_2 = 163 (4t + 2) s^2$, $c_0 = t+1$.
The result is $f(b) = 163 (4 t + 2) (sb)^2 + 163 sb + t + 1$, where $E(f(b))$ is divisible by $1 + 652 (sb)^2$.
Again we may take $s=1$.  This case includes $n = 490$ (for $t=0,b=1$), $n=817$ (for $t=1,b=-1$), and 
$n=979$ (for $t=0, b=-2$).

Comment: It's interesting that you can get a complete classification of quadratic $f(b)$ such that $E(f(b))$ is divisible by $e_2 b^2+e_0$.  If this could be generalized to $E(f(b))$ divisible by $e_2 b^2+e_1 b+e_0$, that would account for all four polynomials in the original post plus your new one, and indicate whether any additional solutions exist.  I started to apply your method to the general case, but it requires some careful analysis, which I won't have time to complete until later.

Comment: I also wanted to mention that in your new polynomial, you have to require $b$ nonzero to avoid prime values of $E(f(b))$.  When $b=0$, one of the factors of $E(f(b))$ reduces to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we should separate two parts of the problem.

a) for what quadratic polynomials $f(b)$  with rational coefficients does $E(f(b))$ have a quadratic factor?

b) when does $f(b)$ from (a) take integers to integers?

For a) the general answer appears to be

$$f(b) =c_2 b^2 + c_1 b + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{d^4 - c_1^2 d^2 - 163 c_2^2}{4 c_2 d^2}
$$

for arbitrary rational $d, c_1, c_2$ such that $c_2 d \ne 0$.  This includes as special cases
$f_1(a,b)$ with $d=1, c_1 = 1-a, c_2 = a$, $f_2(a,b)$ with $d=1, c_1 = -1, c_2 = 4a+2$,
$f_3(a,b)$ with $d=1, c_1 = 1+a-a^2, c_2 = (a+1) a$,
$f_4(a,b)$ with $d=1, c_1 =\frac{2+3a-a^2}{2}, c_2 = \frac{a^2+a}{2}$,
and  my previous answer $c_2 b^2 + c_1 b + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{163 c_2}{4 c_1^2}$ with $d=c_1$.

For (b) we need $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{d^4 - c_1^2 d^2 - 163 c_2^2}{4 c_2 d^2}$ to be an integer and $c_1$ and $c_2$ either both integers or both half-odd-integers.  I don't know the general solution to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Every integer $m$ such that $E(m)$ is composite, say $E(m) = u v$, can be obtained from a quadratic integer polynomial $f(b)$ for which $E(f(b))$ factors into two quadratics: namely 
$$ f(b) = (u + v - 2 m + 1) b^2 + (u - v) b + m$$
where 
$$E(f(b)) = ((u + v - 2 m + 1) b^2 + (- 2 m + 2 u + 1)b + u)((u + v - 2 m + 1) b^2 
+ (2 m - 2 v - 1) b + v)$$

Note that $f(0) = m$ and the two factors give us $u$ and $v$ at $b=0$.