# Is there any efficient formula/expression that is guaranteed to always generate primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

There are lots of formulas, like $f(n) = n^2 + n + 41$, that generate lots of primes very often. But they're not guaranteed to always generate only prime numbers.

Do there exist any simple/efficient formulas $f(n)$ that are guaranteed to generate a sequence of only prime numbers for each $n$? Or has it been proven that such a formula can't exist?

To be clear, I don't want a trivial formula like $f(n)=7$ (which technically always produces only prime numbers). And it has to be decently simple/efficient, meaning that things like [Willans' Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#Formulas_based_on_Wilson%27s_theorem) don't count.

Comment: Yes, it is proved that a polynomial $f\in \Bbb Z[x]$ producing only primes is constant, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466070/a-nonconstant-polynomial-q-with-q01-attains-infinitely-many-composite-val?rq=1). But for polynomials in $26$ variables it is possible.

Comment: "Jones, Sato, Wada, and Wiens have also found a polynomial of degree 25 in 26 variables whose positive values are exactly the prime numbers (Flannery and Flannery 2000, p. 51)."

Comment: @DietrichBurde That's amazing! I had no idea that was possible. [This MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132954/the-jones-sato-wada-wiens-polynomial-for-prime-numbers-and-differential-calculus) states the polynomial, as well as links to [their paper](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/JonesSatoWadaWiens.pdf), for anyone interested.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. It seems that you want a way to generate *primes*, and that it must be a *formula or expression*. Willans's formula is exactly a way to generate the *primes*, translated into the language of a mathematical *formula*, and so would seem to be exactly what you are after, yet you say that it doesn't count...

Comment: It is even worse. We know no efficient method to construct ANY not already known large prime number. We can only sieve out small prime factors followed by a primality test to find one.

Comment: The few known examples of prime generating formulas are useless in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, no. Indeed, the first sentence of the ["Formulas for primes" section of the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Formulas_for_primes) is "There is no known efficient formula for primes." I recommend clicking on the "Main article: Formula for primes" for further information.

To prove that "such a formula" doesn't exist, one would first need to rigorously define the class of formulas one is interested in.