# Prove or disprove: $n^2-n+11$ is a prime for every positive integer $n$

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers

I'm having difficulty proving this statement.

> For every positive integer $n$, $n^2-n+11$ is a prime

So I know the obvious, that a prime can only be divided by $1$ and itself, but I'm not sure how to turn that into some generic equation to compare to the one mentioned in the question. Could someone give me a start?

Comment: Hint: consider the case of $n=11$.

Comment: Ah, so a counter example to disprove it?

Comment: Yes, precisely!

Comment: Duh, thanks a lot!

Comment: Not that it matters, but if you need them, I have plenty more counterexamples where that one came from ...

Comment: Just for your information, there are no closed formula functions in general that are prime for all $n$.

Comment: @Gregory: What about the constant function $2$?

Comment: Don't be smart, lol.  You know what I meant.  More precisely, there are no non-constant closed formula functions $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb N$ all of whose values are prime s.t. $|f(\mathbb N)|=\infty$.

Comment: @Gregory: Hehe. Sorry, I could not resist. I suppose that depends on your definition of closed form, doesn't it? Does Mills' formula count as closed form?

Comment: @ADH Note that a number is prime if and only if it has exactly two **distincts** divisors. In particular $1$ is **not** prime although it is only divisible by $1$ and itself.

Comment: @Regret, Mill's would be if we could know what $A$ is without first finding all primes in the first place.  I should have said no "known" formula because I don't think it has been proven that no such formula can exist in principle.

Comment: @Surb such distinction is really unnecessary, since it isn't meaningful to talk about a "number of divisors" at all, if we are not talking about distinct divisors. (If we aren't talking about "distinct divisors", then any number has infinite divisors. It can be taken for granted, by virtue of the fact that we are specifying number in the first place.)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\ f(11n)\, =\, 11\,(11n^2\!-n+1)\,$ always prime implies $\,11n^2\!-n+1 = 1 $ for all $\,n>0,\,$ contra a nonzero quadratic has at most $2$ roots.

**Remark** $\ $ I presented the proof this way because [exactly the same proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/817110/242) shows that *any* nonconstant polynomials cannot produce only primes. You may find it much more instructive to prove this more general statement.

Answer (score -2):

let $n=11$

$n^2$ is a multiple of $11$.

A multiple of $11$ minus $n$(a multiple of 11) is also a multiple of 11.

When a multiple of 11 is added to a multiple of 11, it is again a multiple of 11.

It means, 11 is a factor of the number -> the number has a proper factor 11.

Therefore $n$ is not prime.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I see no point in this lengthy argument, when $n=11$, we obviously have $n^2- n+11 = (11)^2$, which is not prime. (And you don't mean to say $n$ is not prime I suppose).