# Prove or disprove $\forall n \in N$ integer $2n^2 - 4n + 31$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm stuck on this problem. In general, what is the approach to prove that some number is prime?

Comment: What happens when $\, N = 31?\ $

Comment: No non-constant polynomial with integer coefficients produces only primes.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table%5Bfactor%5B2n%5E2-4n%2B31%5D,%7Bn,1,40%7D%5D

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/817110/242) for a proof that only constant polynomials can always take prime values.

Answer (score 9):

What happens to $2n^2-4n+31$ when $n=31$?

Answer (score 4):

On the other hand, there are infinitely many pairs $n,w$ for which
$$ 2 n^2 - 4 n w + 31 w^2 $$
is prime. You should find some of those.

Answer (score 2):

For any polynomial, if you substitute in the constant term for the variable, the value will be divisible by the constant term.  As long as the constant is not $1$ and the value is not the same as the constant, you will have a composite value.  For your example, if we set $n$ to $31$ we get $2\cdot 31^2-4\cdot 31+31=1829=59\cdot 31$.  Using any multiple of the constant term works as well.

Answer (score 1):

As $2n^2 - 4n + 31=n(2n-4)+31$, hence for each $n=31k\in \mathbb{N}$, we have $$2n^2 - 4n + 31=31k(62k-4)+31=31\left( k(62k-4)+1   \right),$$ and so it is not a prime.