# A Number theory & polynomial question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $p$ is a some polynomial with integer coefficients, $M$ is an integer such that $p(n)$ is prime for every $n\ge M $. Then $p$ is constant.

Please help , I have no clue how to prove it.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Having "no clue" is no good excuse for not including what you think about the problem and what you have tried. So please edit your question to include what you have tried and we can hint accordingly without spoiling the fun of solving the problem!

Comment: if $\,p(x\!+\!M)\,$ is prime for all $\,x\in\Bbb N\,$ [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/817110/242) $\,\deg p(x\!+\!M) = 0\,$ so $\,\deg p(x) = \deg p(x\!+\!M) = 0\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $p$ is not constant. We know that $p(M)=q$ with $q$ prime. Since $p$ is not constant $\lim_{n \to \infty} |p(M+nq)|=\infty$. That is, for $n$ big enough, $|p(M+nq)|>q$. But notice that
$$
p(M+nq) \equiv p(M) \equiv 0 \ mod \ q.
$$
So $M+nq \geq M$ and $p(M+nq)$ is a composite number.

Comment: why does p(M+nq) = p(M) = 0modq  happens ?

Comment: $p=a_kx^k+ \cdots a_1x+a_0$ for $a_i$ integers. Then $p(M+nq)=a_k(M+nq)^k+ \cdots + a_1(M+nq)+a_0$. But we know $M+nq \equiv M \ mod \ q$. So...