# How to show that a polynomial $f(x)$ is composite for infinitely many integers $x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

> Let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+ \ldots +a_nx^n$ be a polynomial with integer
>   coefficients, where $a_n>0$ and $n \ge 1$. Prove that $f(x)$ is
>   composite for infinitely many integers $x$.

[Proving a polynomial $f(x)$ composite for infinitely many $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86018/proving-a-polynomial-fx-composite-for-infinitely-many-x)

Can anyone explain why in answer to this question( in the link given above ) such an $m$ always exist such that $f(m)\neq\pm 1$?

Comment: It's $f(m) \neq \pm 1$. And such an $m$ exists because $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \lvert f(x)\rvert = +\infty$ if $\deg f > 0$.

Comment: Fixed that , thanks for mentioning.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Is there any other method to show this to a person who don't know about limits ?

Comment: Suppose no such $m$ existed, then $f(m) = \pm 1$ for all $m$. If $f(m) = 1$ or $-1$ for all $m$, then it is constant which contradicts the assumption that $f$ isn't constant. If however it achieves both $1$ and $-1$, by the IVT, it must achieve all values in between which contradicts the assumption that $f(m) = \pm 1$ for all $m$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, okie in that case $0$ will be the required integer, as the only integer between -1 and 1 is 0.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, but we need $f(m)$ to be an integer

Comment: @CameronWilliams $m$ is an integer in that answer, one is only interested in the values at integer arguments.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, yeah that is fine, basically if $f(m)=1 or -1$ for all $m$ then $f$ must also attains $0$ somewhere, and in this case also we can find a prime $p$ such that $p | f(m)$

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh it sure is. I didn't notice the slight difference between the title and question in the OP!

Comment: @Member Without limits: If $f(n) \in \{1,-1\}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, then at least one of $1$ and $-1$ is attained infinitely often. But then $f(x) \mp 1$ is a polynomial with infinitely many zeros, but that contradicts $\deg f \geqslant 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, thanks it was a nice observation.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Can't we also complete the argument given by Cameron Williams.

Comment: @Member I think Daniel's approach is a bit better since it doesn't rely on the intermediate value theorem (which is a bit limit-oriented).

Comment: @CameronWilliams, Yeah I agree his idea was beautiful but I also want to see can't we do this by your approach.

Comment: @Member Actually my suggestion doesn't work as-is since I did not realize that $m$ was taken to be integral because of the mismatch of your title and question initially. Using the IVT forces you to look at all points between two points, but since you are only interested in integer points, I don't think it works out.