# $S=\{a,a+d,a+2d,...\}$ where $a,d$ are natural numbers. Show that there are infinitely many composite numbers in S.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

It is easy to prove when $a>1$. Each element in this set is of the form $a+nd$. Whenever n is a multiple of a, then $n=ak$, thus $a+nd=a+ak=a(1+k)$. Thus n is composite. But the difficulty comes when $a=1$. I cannot find a way. Any hint will be much appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you have proved it for $a>1$, the $a=1$ case is easily done by writing $S=\{A-d, A, A+d, A+2d, \cdots\}$ where $A=a+d>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a\geq 1, d \geq 1$ let $n=1+k(a+d)$, then
$$a+nd=(kd+1)(a+d).$$
Notice that $a+d\geq 2$.

More generally, if you have a polynomial $f(x)$ over integers and $n=f(m)$ for integers $n,m$, then $f(m+kn)$ is a multiple of $n$ for any integer $k$ (see [Proving a polynomial $f(x)$ composite for infinitely many $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86018/proving-a-polynomial-fx-composite-for-infinitely-many-x)). In your case you have $f(x)=dx+a$, so we have $f(1)=d+a$ and $d+a\mid f(1+k(d+a))$.

Answer (score 4):

Take $n = k^2d-2k$  where $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $$1+nd = 1+k^2d^2-2kd =(kd-1)^2$$

so there is also infinitely many squares in it.